# Get data from secured websites into Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I tried to get some data from secured websites. however, I cannot log in to the website thru Power BI application. any possible ways to get data?

[image]

what I expect is to get data from secured websites by using Power BI application

Comment: If the site is password protected, there are two options.
Use Power Automate to get the data and then import them into Power BI or create a custom connector. There is also a possibility that you can not get the data from this website, which is it you are trying to use?

Comment: How is it "secured"?  There are dozens of possible ways, only some of which Power BI can support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power bi cannot just get data from any secured website. The web connector do not pass the username and password to the web to fetch data. As a workaround, if the website exposes the REST API, you could use the API method.

Here is the link for an example of Rest API, you can ask the website owner for accessibility

[enter link description here](https://zappysys.com/blog/howto-import-json-rest-api-power-bi/?gclid=CjwKCAiAyfybBhBKEiwAgtB7fpLxURwhF3MOILfayruRSyBJ4XsWdytc3wpc4oQhq36Ml9SjtYosARoCUAcQAvD_BwE)